# Theil Index Python vs R

Tags: python, r

I am trying to calculate the Theil index in python and R, but with the given functions, I am getting different answers. Here is the formula that I am trying to use:

[image: Theil Calculation]

Using the ineq package in R, I can easily get the Theil index:

```
library(ineq)
x=c(26.1,16.1,15.5,15.4,14.8,14.7,13.7,12.1,11.7,11.6,11,10.8,10.8,7.5)
Theil(x)
0.04152699
```

This implementation seems to make sense and I can look at the code provided to see what exact calculations that are happening and it seems to follow the formula (deleting zeros when I get have them in order to take the log):

```
getAnywhere(Theil )
Out[24]:
A single object matching ‘Theil’ was found
It was found in the following places
  package:ineq
  namespace:ineq
with value

function (x, parameter = 0, na.rm = TRUE) 
{
    if (!na.rm && any(is.na(x))) 
        return(NA_real_)
    x <- as.numeric(na.omit(x))
    if (is.null(parameter)) 
        parameter <- 0
    if (parameter == 0) {
        x <- x[!(x == 0)]
        Th <- x/mean(x)
        Th <- sum(x * log(Th))
        Th <- Th/sum(x)
    }
    else {
        Th <- exp(mean(log(x)))/mean(x)
        Th <- -log(Th)
    }
    Th
}
```

However, I see that this question has been answered previously before for python [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20279458/implementation-of-theil-inequality-index-in-python) . The code is here, but the answers do not match for some reason:

```
def T(x):
    n = len(x)
    maximum_entropy = math.log(n)
    actual_entropy = H(x)
    redundancy = maximum_entropy - actual_entropy
    inequality = 1 - math.exp(-redundancy)
    return redundancy,inequality 

def Group_negentropy(x_i):
    if x_i == 0:
        return 0
    else:
        return x_i*math.log(x_i)

def H(x):
    n = len(x)
    entropy = 0.0
    summ = 0.0
    for x_i in x: # work on all x[i]
        summ += x_i
        group_negentropy = Group_negentropy(x_i)
        entropy += group_negentropy
    return -entropy
x=np.array([26.1,16.1,15.5,15.4,14.8,14.7,13.7,12.1,11.7,11.6,11,10.8,10.8,7.5])
T(x)
(512.62045438815949, 1.0)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is not stated explicitly in the other question, but that implementation expects its input to be normalized, so that each `x_i` is a *proportion* of income, not an actual amount.  (That's why the other code has that `error_if_not_in_range01` function and raises an error if any `x_i` is not between 0 and 1.)

If you normalize your `x`, you'll get the same result as the R code:

```
>>> T(x/x.sum())
(0.041526988117662533, 0.0406765553418974)
```

(The first value there is what R is reporting.)